# ¿Como generar un PDF en Java con un archivo .jasper?

Tags: java, pdf

Estoy utilizando JasperSoft para crear mis reportes, utilizo una tabla para mostrar los datos que necesito, la cual se alimenta directamente desde la base de datos mediante una query. Al observar la vista previa dentro de Jaspersoft muestra los datos correctamente, compilo el reporte y me crea un archivo .jasper. Lo que necesito saber es como mostrar dicho reporte en mi aplicación Java en formato PDF.

*Nota: No quiero alimentar el reporte desde la aplicación, porque como ya mencioné la tabla se llena mediante una query.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. Dices que necesitas "convertir el archivo .jasper a PDF y generarlo en la aplicación" pero por otro lado dices que has "encontrado la forma de generarlo dentro de Java desde la aplicación pero tu lo estás llenando desde JasperSoft". ¿Tu PDF necesita ser generado dinámicamente en base a input de usuario o es que necesitas generarlo una vez y tenerlo como recurso estático?

Comment: Hola @LuiggiMendoza , creo que entiendo a cursosizi. Lo que se refiere a vista previa debe ser el iReport, pero ahora al usarlo desde un programa generado en java existe dos formas, que tu hagas el DAO para obtener los datos y pasar los beans al reporte, que es lo que encontro en internet o que el archivo de reporte auto ejecute el query, que como menciono en mi respuesta necesita pasar una conexion, solo abria que cambiar su ultima linea, si es muy extraña :D

Comment: Disculpas por no haberme dado a entender correctamente, editaré la pregunta para hacerla mas comprensible.

Comment: Según veo, tu pregunta básicamente es: *No tengo parámetros que pasarle al Jasper, ¿aún así debo prepararlo desde mi aplicación Java?* y la respuesta es **sí**, sino ¿de qué otra manera se va a generar el pdf? Si lo que quieres es generarlo desde el IDE (iReport, Jaspersoft, equis) con los datos que tienes, tu PDF sería un recurso estático para tu aplicación. Si los datos en tu tabla pueden variar, pues entonces debes utilizar código Java para generar el PDF. Si vas por la vía programática, tienes 2 maneras, pero para seguir apoyándote necesito que expliques qué necesitas en verdad.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza No necesito pasarle ningun parametro desde la aplicación, pero debo mostrar el pdf que se genera en Jaspersoft, ese reporte ya esta listo con la query que extrae los registros directamente de la base de datos.

Así que por medio de un boton quisiera visualizar el reporte en la aplicación, pero no he encontrado una manera de hacerlo.

Comment: El hecho de que generes el PDF desde Java no significa que debas pasarle parámetros. Si tu query no recibe parámetros, no significa que la tabla no sea modificable por otros procesos. Es decir, si yo ejecuto el query de tu reporte hoy devuelve 5 resultados, si lo ejecuto mañana devuelve 10, o quizás devuelve 5 pero con diferentes resultados. ¿Tu query funciona así o es que **siempre** va a devolver los mismos resultados porque la tabla o tablas sobre las que se ejecuta no varían en absoluto?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Los resultados que se muestran en la tabla si pueden variar.

Comment: Entonces no te sirve generar el PDF desde el IDE sino desde la aplicación. El hecho de que tu query no necesite parámetros **no significa** que no debas generar el query desde tu aplicación. Puesto que no tienes parámetros, solo manda el mapa de parámetros vacío, no lo mandes como `null`.

Answer (score 3):

Para contestar bien tu pregunta necesitamos que nos aclares que producto estas usando, Jaspersoft es una compañía, no un producto. Por ejemplo cuando dices que "la vista previa dentro de Jaspersoft", no sabemos si te refieres al diseñador Jaspersoft® Studio o al servidor de reportes JasperReports® Server.

Los reportes normalmente se diseñan en Jaspersoft® Studio o IReport®, y se guardan en un archivo `.jrxml`, dicho archivo se compila `.jasper` y este último se puede convertir a una multitud de formatos, incluyendo PDF. 
La conversión de .jrxml a .jasper a PDF se puede hacer desde el mismo Studio, en el JasperReports® Server o desde tu propia aplicación usando JasperReports® Library, este último escenario es el que te hemos estado intentando resolver.

En todo caso te incluyo mi codigo, (por cierto, tampoco nos has dicho si se trata de una aplicacion web o de escritorio, este ejemplo es de una aplicación web)

```
//Prefiero usar el .jrxml a la aplicacion que el .jasper por que es mas facil de versionar
String sourceFileName = rutaFisica + "MiReporte.jrxml";            
File theFile = new File(sourceFileName);
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(theFile);//Se carga el archivo

//Si el reporte va a tener un query fijo, puedes omitir este paso
JRDesignQuery newQuery = new JRDesignQuery();
newQuery.setText("SELECT * FROM miTabla WHERE X = Y");
jasperDesign.setQuery(newQuery);

Map parameters = new HashMap();//Parametros que usa el jasperreports
//Este parametro sirve para meter una funcion que el reporte va a ejecutar para encontrar la ruta fisica de sus imagenes
parameters.put("REPORT_FILE_RESOLVER", new FileResolver() {
                public File resolveFile(String fileName) {
                    return new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("") + "\\mis_imagenes\\"+fileName); 
                }
            });
//Se compila el archivo a .jasper
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);

//Aqui se llena el reporte (se ejecuta la consulta)
JasperPrint print = new JasperPrint();
print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, getConnection());
byte[] pdfBytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(print);
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=" + nombreArchivo + ".pdf");
response.getOutputStream().write(pdfBytes);
response.flushBuffer();
```

Por último, viendo tu nota final:

> *Nota: No quiero alimentar el reporte desde la aplicación, porque como ya     mencioné la tabla se llena mediante una query.

Y viendo las ediciones de tu pregunta

> no he encontrado la forma de generar el reporte dentro de JAVA; los códigos que he encontrado en internet son de personas que llenan sus reportes desde la aplicación, pero yo ya lo estoy llenando directamente desde Jaspersoft

me hace creer (y corrígeme si me equivoco) que piensas que el archivo .jasper ya incluye los datos con los que se alimenta el reporte, y que no se ocupa "alimentar" por la aplicación, el archivo .jasper es tan solo la versión compilada del archivo .jrxml, si abres este último con un editor de texto, verás que se encuentra la definición de tu consulta (`SELECT * FROM ...`) pero **no** tus datos, el reporte se debe conectar a la base de datos cada vez que se genere el PDF, por eso el `getConnection()` en mi ejemplo.

O igual ninguno de nosotros te entendimos, y lo unico que quieres es ligar tu JasperReports® Server a tu aplicación web.

Por favor contesta, aun si ya resolviste el problema. Para que nos quitemos de la duda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Respuesta original en SO ingles : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8569883/3613462

> Vamos viendo, así es como funciona: JasperFillManager retorna un JasperPrint object, entonces:
>
> ```
> // obtenemos la plantilla JRXML como un stream
> InputStream template = JasperReportsApplication.class
>     .getResourceAsStream("/sampleReport.xml");
> // compilamos el reporte desde el stream
> JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(template);
> // llenamos el reporte en un print object, listo para exportar
> JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, new HashMap<String, String>());
> // Lo exportamos!
> File pdf = File.createTempFile("output.", ".pdf");
> JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, new FileOutputStream(pdf));
> ```
>
> Disfruta!

Comment: Yo estaba por responder algo similar pero encontré algunas inconsistencias en la pregunta como esto: *no he encontrado la forma de generar el reporte dentro de JAVA; los códigos que he encontrado en internet son de personas que llenan sus reportes desde la aplicación, pero yo ya lo estoy llenando directamente desde Jaspersoft*

Answer (score 0):

En lugar pasar los datos desde Java, necesitas pasarle la cadena de conexion para que ejecute el query que tiene dentro, que mencionas que ya generar correctamente tu reporte

```
jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conexion);
```

Mas o menos completo seria

```
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();// Creamos mapa de parametros de ayuda
parameters.put("algunParametro", x);
parameters.put("tipo", y);
Connection conexion = crearConexion(); // creamos la conexion a la base de datos
jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(rutaArchivo);//Cargamos al jasper    

jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, conexion);// llenamos el reporte, indicando la conexion a base de datos

JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter(); //Creamos el exporter a PDF
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);//EDIT 
exporter.exportReport();
return baos.toByteArray(); //y obtenemos los valiosos bytes generados ;)
```

En mi caso simpre me gusta regresar el arreglo de bytes del reporte, pero usando otros metodos puedes manejarlo de diferente forma.

Comment: ¿Qué es `baos`? ¿Si es un `ByteArrayOutputStream` no sería mejor devolverlo como stream en lugar de arreglo o *wrapearlo* en un `BufferedOutputStream` para no cargar todos esos bytes en memoria de golpe? Sobretodo si estás generando archivos PDF pesados, te puedes consumir la RAM muy rápido.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Creo que tienes razon, es la costumbre en unos minutos hago el edit

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que uso es en una clase (AbstractaJasperReports):

```
/**
* reporte como tal del sistema de archivos
*/
private static JasperReport report;

/**
* reporte, pero ya lleno con la información que trae el query interno
*/
private static JasperPrint reportFilled;

/**
* visor donde se va a mostrar el reporte
*/
private static JasperViewer viewer;    

public static void crearInforme(Connection conexion, String ruta, Map parametros)
{
  try
  {
    report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(ruta);
    reportFilled = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, conexion);
  } catch (JRException e)
  {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public static void verVisor()
{
  viewer = new JasperViewer(reportFilled, false);
  viewer.setVisible(true);
}
```

Y luego para llamarlo hago:

```
// creo la conexión a la BBDD
ConexionBBDD conn = new ConexionBBDD();

HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();

parametros.put("clave", valor);

AbstractaJasperReports.crearInforme((Connection) conn.getConexion(), "./src/rutaAlJasper/ficheroJasper.jasper", parametros);

AbstractaJasperReports.verVisor();
```

Answer (score 0):

es posible hacer una integración de una aplicación web en java con netbeans y la aplicación de JasperReports Server, y desde la aplicación web obtener los reportes que se encuentran en JasperReport Server en PDF u otro formato con un solo botón o una petición desde la aplicación web.

Saludos.