# ¿como llenar un reporte .jasper que contiene sub reportes con un HashMap?

Tags: java

Debo llenar una plantilla .jrxml que contiene sub reportes dentro:

Es decir, varias secciones que muestres cierta información y algunas estarán condicionadas para que se mostré la información.
Sin embargo, yo ignorante del manejo de plantillas para la generación de reportes, no tengo la menor idea de como enviarle los parámetros a dicha plantilla.

¿Alguien me pueda orientar en dicha practica?

La plantilla es la siguente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.5.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.5.1  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="pruebaMF" pageWidth="612" pageHeight="792" whenNoDataType="NoPages" columnWidth="572" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="3478e215-5465-433f-babf-544956062915">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.scriptlethandling" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.encoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.*"/>
    <import value="java.util.*"/>
    <import value="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.*"/>
    <style name="importeStyle">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[new Boolean("Importe".equalsIgnoreCase(($F{label} != null)? $F{label}.trim() : "") || "Importe:".equalsIgnoreCase(($F{label} != null)? $F{label}.trim() : "") || (($F{label} != null)? $F{label}.trim() : "").indexOf("Importe") > -1)]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#006EC1"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="04cddaeb-a294-4127-915a-4e20525a617a">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="nombreUsuario" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="titulo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="tipoComprobante" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["report/"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="pie" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="rutaImagen" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="rutaImagenIconoTitulo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="textoLegal" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="fechaSistema" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="avisoImportante" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="subtitulo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="tituloInv" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="input" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="label" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="mapaVacioParaSubreportCabecera" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mapaVacioParaSubreportCabecera]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mapa1" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mapa1]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mapa2" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mapa2]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mapa3" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mapa3]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mapa4" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mapa4]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="mapa5" class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[mapa5]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="120" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement key="pdfGenerico_subreportCabecera" x="-20" y="-20" width="612" height="140" uuid="f7065bff-06cb-485d-acb6-8248b6c61c32"/>
                <subreportParameter name="fechaSistema">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{fechaSistema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="titulo">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{titulo}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="tipoComprobante">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{tipoComprobante}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="rutaImagen">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{rutaImagen}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="rutaImagenIconoTitulo">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{rutaImagenIconoTitulo}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="nombreUsuario">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{nombreUsuario}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{mapaVacioParaSubreportCabecera})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "pdfGenerico_subreportCabecera.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="27" splitType="Stretch">
            <line>
                <reportElement isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="36" y="0" width="500" height="1" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true" forecolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="436a41d1-b7e5-4310-8679-5e0b4a5af082"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="36" y="5" width="500" height="21" uuid="b98d4a54-66f1-4cac-bb75-798b771f6e8b"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{mapa1})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} +"pdfsubReport_comprog.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="34">
            <subreport isUsingCache="false" overflowType="Stretch">
                <reportElement x="35" y="6" width="500" height="21" uuid="6f68c68c-20cc-42f3-8dcb-cf22b08045cb"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{mapa2})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} +"pdfsubReport_comprog.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="45">
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="36" y="4" width="500" height="21" uuid="773c6ceb-c8fa-4609-b199-0e0b86148123"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{mapa3})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} +"pdfsubReport_comprog.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="203" y="31" width="161" height="10" uuid="576d64f9-e54c-4cfa-ad44-8b2456344750"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{mapa5})]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} +"simu_comprog.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="32">
            <subreport isUsingCache="false">
                <reportElement x="36" y="6" width="500" height="21" uuid="7a858acb-70eb-4e19-b7c4-d0d729f46333"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{mapa4})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} +"pdfsubReport_comprog.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <lastPageFooter>
        <band height="109" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="557" height="19" uuid="cc7f6679-429b-48b2-aeab-12e1582a4140"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true" isUnderline="false" isStrikeThrough="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{pie}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="36" y="25" width="502" height="51" uuid="d7a25b32-9503-408c-a900-665396cd58ec"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{textoLegal}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="36" y="4" width="502" height="1" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" forecolor="#CCCCCC" uuid="436a41d1-b7e5-4310-8679-5e0b4a5af082">
                    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$P{textoLegal}.equals( new String() )]]></printWhenExpression>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="36" y="5" width="502" height="14" uuid="d7a25b32-9503-408c-a900-665396cd58ec"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{avisoImportante}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </lastPageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

En java, estoy llenando un mapa. Dentro de este mapa manejo 4 mapas mas:

```
public Map<String, Object> rellenaMap(){


final Map<String, Object> mapa = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>(6);
String constante = "Opercacion programada"; 
String bandera = this.getEsPro();
String marca = this.getIsScheledPeriodic();
String importeIngreso="";
try {
    imporIn = NumberFormatUtil.getCurrencyLocale(this.getImporI(), Currency.getInstance(LocaleUtil.cargaLocale()));
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
final Map<String, Object> mapa1 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
final Map<String, Object> mapa2 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
final Map<String, Object> mapa3 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
final Map<String, Object> mapa4 = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();

   mapa1.put("inv.cE",this.getNCuaC());
   mapa1.put("inv.inv",imporIn);
   mapa1.put("inv.fInv",this.getFSeD());
   mapa1.put("inv.preActual", this.getPr());
   mapa1.put("inv.titOpe",this.getTitC());
   mapa1.put("inv.serie",this.getSer());

   mapa.put("inv.mapa1", mapa1);

   mapa2.put("inv.cuen",this.numCCort);
   mapa2.put("inv.cont",this.contInv);   
   mapa2.put("inv.serv",this.servinvf);

   mapa.put("inv.mapa2", mapa2);


   if (marca.equalsIgnoreCase("OK")){

   mapa3.put("opPer.coFs.frec",getPeriodic()); 
   mapa3.put("opPer.coFs.impor",getMonOperadoProg());
   mapa3.put("opPer.coFs.fecha_inicio",getStartDate()); 
   mapa3.put("opPer.coFs.repeticionesLabel",getFecter()); 

   mapa3.put("opPer.coFs.repeticionesLabel",getHowOften());

   mapa.put("inv.mapa3", mapa3);



   }



    if (bandera.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {

        mapa4.put("inv.coVaFs.folProg", this.getFolOper());
        mapa4.put("inv.fecProg", this.getFecOpe());
        mapa4.put("inv.coVaFs.horaProgramada", this.getHrProg());
        mapa4.put("inv.coVaFs.fechaProgramada", this.getFecProg());

        mapa.put("inv.mapa4", mapa4);
    } else {

        mapa4.put("inv.folOpera", this.getFolInt());
        mapa4.put("inv.feOpera",this.getFeOper());

        mapa.put("inv.mapa4", mapa4);

    }


return mapa;
}
```

Sin embargo el resultado es el siguiente :

Solo me coloca el titulo del mapa y la cadena de la sintaxis del mapa en cuestion:

> ```
> Opera : {inv.cE =15325474,
>          inv.inv =$200.00}
>
> programa : { inv.cuen=234824,
>              inv.cont=745264}
> ```

---

No se si no le estoy enviando correctamente los mapas pero se supone que quedarian algo asi:

mapa1

- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.

mapa2

- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.

mapa3

- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.

mapa4

- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.
- etiqueta:dato.

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir más información? El código del jrxml, que tipo de datasource usas, diagramas de bases de datos algún ejemplo de código que ya tengas avanzado y que no entiendas el error. Para Jasper Reports la dinámica es primero el diseño del jrxml después tienes que compilar el jrxml a un archivo jasper (con JasperComplieManager), después tienes que llenar el reporte con un dataSource (con JasperFillManager), y finalizar con la exportación del JasperPrint que obtuviste al llenar el reporte al formato que desees un Excel o un PDF hay más exports disponibles.

Comment: Las respuestas a esta pregunta tienen más ejemplos que podrías usar https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4114/como-generar-un-pdf-en-java-con-un-archivo-jasper?rq=1